# SP2013 Host Web App on WFE and not on CA server

Tags: 2013, web-application, infrastructure

I creating a new SP2013 farm, with 3 servers. A database, a CA and a WFE.

The CA server will only host CentralAdmin, when the WFE will host my differents web apps.

I guess I understand that if I create a new web application, it will be hosted on both SP servers (CA + WFE) because they are part of my farm, right ?

If so, is there a way to "detach" the web app to be only hosted by the WFE server ?

Else I don't really understand the need to install a three-tier farm ...

And by the way, do you recommend me to separate intranet web app from extranet one ? So should I install the intranet web app with the CA and the extranet alone in my WFE ?

Or installing CA alone and web app (nvm intra/extra) on another side is the best practises ?

TIA

Comment: I suggest you go to server features of your CA server and activate only the services needed to maintain central admin, all other services should be deactivated.

Comment: So for you, isolating CA is the right procedure ? and putting web applications (intranet/extranet) together ? I will search the way you suggested me. Thanks for answer

Comment: In this way, I think you will not allow it to take care of other tasks and the only server who can is the WFE. You are welcome.

Comment: I'm wondering if (with luck) have a bookmark about what services is used by CA and what services I should stop or not. Else, I'm going to keep on searching

Comment: I will post it as an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Central administration - Application Management - Under Service Applications click Manage Services on Server .

On the top Right corner you will see the server name. Click on it. Select **CA server**. 
The most important services that have to be stopped are

- "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" (that prevent the server from hosting web app)
- "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service"

It is suggested to deactivate all other services except a service called Central Administration.

In the server name now, select the **WFE server**. Keep all services that you need activated and stop Central Administration service from it.

[Useful technet link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/10afb9b6-6804-4f77-af86-fdc1ac0db141/creating-webapplication-on-web-front-end-from-application-servers-central-administration?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: Can you confirm me you tested this ? Are there side effects ? W/E its a good answer, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never tested. In my CA server Services that are turned on are: Central Administration  
Claims to Windows Token Service 
User Profile Service 
Request Management 
and 3 other services I think that are not relevant to your question

Comment: Let me know if it was successful (logically it has to be).

Comment: Ok, I let only 4 services : CA, Claims to Windows Token Service, SharePoint Server Search, and the last one (not important) Microsoft SP Foundation Incoming email. I'm about to create the web app and see if CA server host IIS site. Right now, CA seems working well.

Comment: I am happy to hear that !!
Feel free to mark it as an answer :P

Comment: Ok, last comment. you should update your answer with what I'll provide, futur users will see the answer clearly. the real service that need to be stop is "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application", that prevent the server from hosting web app. But still hosting CA web app, Idk why. I think you just need to leave CA and disable the service I mentionned before, plus "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service", as this blog says : http://goo.gl/K67lBb

Comment: I'm waiting your update to mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Updated 
I am really glad it worked. Maybe when  i add more servers to my farm I will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It has never been correct that Foundation Web should only run on FEs. Prior to 2016, SharePoint wasn't smart about where timer jobs would run. This may cause certain timer jobs (typically custom) to fail.

Even with 2016/2019 with their intelligent routing of timer jobs, the back end servers should run Foundation Web and you should point your search crawler boxes at those servers (typically using hosts files to override DNS). This reduces the resource consumption on your end user FEs providing increased responsiveness for your end users.